# How to sort customer names by items purchased in SQL

Tags: sql

Sorry new to this but,

I need to sort customer names by total quantity of items purchased by them, in desc order.
the purchased amount in the table is known as Inv_number

I would need the customer name and than the sum. This is what it should be
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You've forgot to ask a question. Where are you stuck at, actually?

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, SUM() and ORDER BY.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Should work this way - you have to join the tables for customerinfo (customer in this script) and the items purchased (order_items). For simplicity I only made an example with two tables. if the customer_id is present in a kind of "order" table, you have to join order_items -> order -> customer

```
    SELECT 
x.customer_name,
y.customer_amount
FROM customer x
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    SUM(order_amount) AS customer_amount
    FROM order_items
    GROUP BY customer_id
) y ON x.id = y.customer_id
ORDER BY y.customer_amount DESC;
```

Comment: `LEFT INNER JOIN`? ANSI SQL and most databases have LEFT and RIGHT as reserved words, i.e. need to be delimited if used as table aliases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: Thats correct, just used left/right to explain the join relations better. Modified the example to just x/y alias

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your tables are named or what fields they have on them, so I'll give a generic example:

```
SELECT c.CUST_NAME AS "cust_name",
       SUM(oi.QTY_PURCHASED) AS "sum"
  FROM CUSTOMERS c
  INNER JOIN ORDERS o
    ON o.ID_CUSTOMERS = c.ID_CUSTOMERS
  INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS oi
    ON oi.ID_ORDERS = o.ID_ORDERS
  GROUP BY c.CUST_NAME
  ORDER BY SUM(oi.QTY_PURCHASED) DESC,
           c.CUST_NAME ASC
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=408164490687c5c1cd529215444199ed)